# xml parsing using xpath.js

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

Following is the structure of XML I am working on:

```
      <A>
        <B>
          <C>
            <D>some data</D>
            <D>some data</D>
          </C>
        </B>
        <B>
          <C>
            <D>some data</D>
          </C>
        </B>
      </A>
```

I am using xpath.js to parse this XML.Here are the scenarios

1.

```
      select(xmlData, "//B[1]//D");//length is 2.contains D tags within first B
      select(xmlData, "//B[2]//D");//length is 1.contains D tags within second B
```

2.

```
      select(xmlData, "//C[1]//D");//length is 3.contains all D tags
      select(xmlData, "//C[2]//D");//this is undefined.
```

What is the difference between above stated approaches to obtain D tags as array and why is the output different?

Comment: it works so `(//C)[1]//D` :) i don't know why :(

Comment: I understand so, that when `(//C)[1]//D` - find list off all C and take the 1st. But `//C[1]` is as `//(C[1])` -  find 1st in all groups of sibling. B on the same level and there are 1st and 2nd. C have no sibling C tag, so they 1st in both cases